# I cannot log on to chat

Tags: bug, chat, login

https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global doesn’t work. The “help” / diagnostics page presents me with this information:

> - Test 1: JavaScript – ok
> - Test 2: Cookies – ok
> - Test 3: Messaging – ok
> - Test 4: Storage – ok
> - Test 5: Communication with stackauth.com – failed
>
>   - IFRAMEs – ok
>   - Referrer – failed
>   - JavaScript – ok
>   - Time – ok
>   - Storage – failed

I’m on Chrome 24.0.1312.57 / OS X. I use a plugin to block referrers and third-party cookies. I do *not* block localStorage. Finally, [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) works, only [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com) fails.

The fallback login option via stackexchange.com also fails, “No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting”. When disabling the referrer blocker, this option at least works (but the normal login still doesn’t).

Comment: Try again - I just had issues with accessing StackAuth.com but it seems to back accessible now.

Comment: @tombull89 No change.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Try clearing your cache, then try to refresh.

Comment: @Madara I did that of course.

Comment: And if you disable the plugin that block referrer?

Comment: @Sha That’s not something I want to do.

Comment: @KonradRudolph just for test purpose; if you prove that's the case you can ask to change the login behavior and not require referrer. Then enable the plugin again. :)

Comment: @Sha Makes sense. See update.

Comment: So sounds like the storage is failing... maybe it's full? Try to empty Chrome local storage, unless you have stuff you know you want to keep in there.

Comment: @Sha My local storage isn’t full, I tried clearing it before without success.

Comment: This is **still** broken. Any feedback?!

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue and could not find a solution with the help given.

Going to:

*Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Manage exceptions*

and adding

*[**.*]stackexchange.com*

*[**.*]stackauth.com*

to make sure those sites can communicate third-party cookies and site data fixed the error message and I got

**Storage – ok**

On the login test page.

**For the workaround login** ("*No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting*"), disabling referrer-blockers and (!) https everywhere-plugins seems to be required.

Comment: Oh this sucks. I simply don’t manage to create exceptions for the referrer-blocking which make this work, disabling seems the only option.

Comment: Fantastic! I was having the same issue. I disabled 'HTTPS Everywhere' and the chat is working again. Thanks, buddy.

Comment: Instead of disabling HTTPS Everywhere completely (!!), I checked the "Experimental rules: May cause warnings or breakage. Disabled by default. => Stack Exchange (mixed content)" option in the plugin's configuration option and it worked. Too bad Stackexchange delivers mixed content though :-\